# Having difficulty installing Python on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I'm having some difficulty installing Python on Ubuntu. I don't really understand what the error means. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the steps I'm taking:

1: Install Pyenv:

```
curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash

echo export PATH="/home/adam/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
echo eval "$(pyenv init -)" >> ~/.bashrc
echo eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

2: Install Python:

```
pyenv install --list

pyenv install 3.7.3 <----------- This is where I run into errors.
python --version
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Downloading Python-3.7.3.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.3...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 19.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957/Python-3.7.3/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957/Python-3.7.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957/Python-3.7.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20190429142402.20957/Python-3.7.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [Makefile:1130: install] Error 1
```

EDIT:
It was installed already?? I think my confusion was I tested to see if it was installed:

```
python –version
```

But I changed it to this and now it seems to be working:

```
python3 --version
```

Thank you!

Comment: Python is already installed?!?

Comment: Just `apt install python3`

Answer (score 3):

Your Ubuntu distribution - which appears to be 19.04 - came with Python 3. 
So running `python3 --version` would have worked "out of the box." It seems like the OP was a bit confused about the purpose of pyenv, which is to easily switch between multiple versions of Python.

Here are links that I found helpful:

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#why-not-use-system-python

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md

This particular question might be a duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227854/pyenv-build-failed-ubuntu-15-04-using-python-build-20160509

I had a similar issue using pyenv to install version 3.8.0 on Xubuntu 18.04. Following the answer from nicolas.f.g solved this issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install python with Ubuntu apt package manager

`sudo apt python3`

if you're trying to install that specific version of python you may want to consider downloading and building it from source

the error you're getting is because zlib is not installed on your machine, you can install it with

`sudo apt install zlib1g`